# Can a non-type template argument whose type is specified with a placeholder for a deduced class type be passed to another template in C++2a?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

```cpp
template<auto>
struct S {};

template<S>
struct T {};

using T0 = T<S<0>{}>; // compiles

template<S s>
using T1 = T<s>; // fails
```

`T0` compiles with GCC 9.1 but `T1` does not:

```
error: class template argument deduction failed
error: no matching function for call to 'S(S<...auto...>)'
```

Is this expected behavior in C++2a?

**EDIT:**
The compilation failure appears to occur whenever the type is deduced, not specifically when a placeholder for a deduced class type is used:

```cpp
template<auto s>
using T1 = T<s>; // also fails
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T0` should be ill-formed because `S<0>` does not have strong structural equality.

`T1` should be ill-formed, no diagnostic required, because as it stands there is no specialization of `T1` that would be valid (because there is no specialization of `S` that has strong structural equality).

---

This is because the requirement on class types as non-type template parameters is, from [[temp.param]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#param-4):

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - a literal type that has strong structural equality ([class.compare.default]),
> - an lvalue reference type,
> - a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]), or
> - a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).

```
template<S>
struct T {};
```

falls into the last case. But when we try `T<S<0>{}>`, and we deduce the placeholder `S` as `S<0>`  from CTAD, we hit [[temp.arg.nontype]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#arg.nontype-1):

> If a deduced parameter type is not permitted for a template-parameter declaration ([temp.param]), the program is ill-formed.

Which takes us back to the original reference and now we require something called "strong structural equality." This is defined in [[class.compare.default]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.compare.default#4) as:

> A type C has *strong structural equality* if, given a glvalue `x` of type `const C`, either:
>
> - `C` is a non-class type and `x <=> x` is a valid expression of type `std::strong_­ordering` or `std::strong_­equality`, or
> - `C` is a class type where all of the following hold:
>
>   - All of `C`'s base class subobjects and non-static data members have strong structural equality.
>   - `C` has no mutable or volatile non-static data members.
>   - At the end of the definition of `C`, overload resolution performed for the expression `x == x` succeeds and finds either a friend or public member `==` operator that is defined as defaulted in the definition of `C`.

In our case, we're a class type, but while we all our subobjects have strong structural equality (trivially as we have no subobjects), we do *not* have the appropriate `operator==`. To fix that:

```
template <auto>
struct S {
    friend bool operator==(S const&, S const&) = default;
};
```

And now everything *should* compile (but doesn't because gcc doesn't completely support this yet, and indeed doesn't even let you declare the required defaulted `operator==`).